# Nhibernate Concurrency between multiple session

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, concurrency, locking, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table that consists of a column of pre-populated numbers. My API using Nhibernate grabs the first 10 rows where 'Used' flag is set as false. 
What would be the best possible way to avoid concurrency issue when multiple session try to grab row from the table? 
After selecting the row, I can update the flag column to be True so subsequent calls will not use the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With such a general context, it could be done that way:

```
// RepeatableRead ensures the read rows does not get concurrently updated by another
// session.
using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{
    var entities = session.Query<Entity>()
        .Where(e => !e.Used)
        .OrderBy(e => e.Id)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
    foreach(var entity in entities)
    {
        e.Used = true;
    }
    // If your session flush mode is not the default one and does not cause
    // commits to flush the session, add a session.Flush(); call before committing.
    tran.Commit();
    return entities;
}
```

It is simple. It may fail with a deadlock, in which case you would have to throw away the session, get a new one, and retry.

Using an optimistic update pattern could be an alternate solution, but this requires some code for recovering from failed attempts too.

Using a no explicit lock solution, which will not cause deadlock risks, could do it, but it will require more queries:

```
const int entitiesToObtain = 10;
// Could initialize here with null instead, but then, will have to check
// for null after the while too.
var obtainedEntities = new List<Entity>();
while (obtainedEntities.Count == 0)
{
    List<Entity> candidates;
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        candidatesIds = session.Query<Entity>()
            .Where(e => !e.Used)
            .Select(e => e.Id)
            .OrderBy(id => id)
            .Take(entitiesToObtain)
            .ToArray();
    }
    if (candidatesIds.Count == 0)
        // No available entities.
        break;

    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var updatedCount = session.CreateQuery(
            @"update Entity e set e.Used = true
                where e.Used = false
                    and e.Id in (:ids)")
            .SetParameterList("ids", candidatesIds)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
        if (updatedCount == candidatesIds.Length)
        {
            // All good, get them.
            obtainedEntities = session.Query<Entity>()
                .Where(e => candidatesIds.Contains(e.Id))
                .ToList();
            tran.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            // Some or all of them were no more available, and there
            // are no reliable way to know which ones, so just try again.
            tran.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

This uses [NHibernate DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html#batch-direct) as suggested [here](/a/2244708/1178314).  A [strongly typed alternative](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying) is available in NHibernate v5.0.